# Securing an API called by the end users of a client

Tags: rest, api, security, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am building an API meant to be sold to various clients. These clients will be given an API Key or something similar and they'll use the API in a widget on their website.

The end users of the clients' website must be able to use the widget anonymously (no login).

Workflow:

[image]

My current idea is to have the Client's server retrieve a temporary key and use that in the webpage. The End user's browser will use that temporary key to call our API.

Is there any reason why this is not a good practice and/or insecure?

Or is there a better good practice solution? Can I for exmaple use OAuth 2 for this?

Comment: Does the client website have to call your API from the browser? Is it a SPA?

Comment: Well the initial plan involved the client calling our API on the end user's behalf. That idea won't let us limit the calls though, in case someone wants to scrape the data. What is an SPA?

Comment: A SPA is a Single Page Application - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application. If your client is calling the API, then all interactions with your API should only be allowed from your clients server, not the end users browser. Was that your intent?

Comment: It's not an SPA. It's just a widget that the client can include in their website. Right now it works like you said - the client's server calls us. The problem with that is that we need to see who is calling on their side to make sure no-one is scraping our data.

Comment: As you have no relationship or consent from the end-user it seems inappropriate for you to know the end-user identity.

Comment: If you need to know the end users identity, you could require a customer header on the API that the client needs to set for every call they make to your API. The problem with this is that it doesn't guarantee the ID you get is for the end user making the request, you just have to trust the client to set it properly.

Comment: We don't need to know the users' identity, just some information about them to be able to mitigate scraping. I.e. Ip, user agent, js, stuff like that

Comment: I would suggest using @Dan H approach. Use OAuth or another JWT service like Keycloak to store and control over a Single Sign On method the authenticity of the client server. Each client server will have a user:password that they will use to get a token and send this token to get authorized in your API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to secure your API from the clients app. So, for that you can use OAuth 2 with Client Credentials grant type and setup each client as an app so they each get their own set of key/secret credentials.

Since you don't know anything about the end user, but still need to track them, require an endUserId custom header on every request to your API and you'll just have to trust the client to provide you with a valid id for the end user making the request.

To setup OAuth, use an existing library or OAuth service. I don't recommend writing your own. If you can spend some money, [Okta](https://www.okta.com) and [Auth0](https://auth0.com) are good choices. If your API is written in .net, you can use [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer) as a free option.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, this is the idea I was talking about in the question but using oauth to create the key. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but I'm suggesting to not give that key to the end users browser. The client app would be the one to interact with your API. But, if you want to give the access token back to the users browser, make sure it's lifespan is very short. This will inherently cause more complexity due to the browser needing to get a new token if it sits idle for longer than the tokens lifespan.

Comment: Right, that was what I was thinking of - a temporary key that the client gets from our API and uses in their webpage. I sense that you're saying that's a bad idea and I can see that it could be.

I'm not sure I understand your answer though. Who is sending the endUserId custom header? The end user's browser or the client? And how is that id created?

Comment: By user Id I'm not referring to anything specific. It's just some identifier of that user. In my answer, I'm assuming the client application knows who the end user is and therefore could send you some id that identifies the end user. For example, when the user interacts with their browser in a way that the page/widget needs information from your API, their browser would make a request to the client app. In doing so, the client app should know who the user is, and be able to send some type of info (in the header) that identifies the end user with the request to your API.

Comment: Well that's the thing - the users are browsing the client's website anonymously. To simplify the integration for our client, we need to assume that they don't collect any information from the user.

Comment: I see. I think we are on the same page now. So, if the widget loaded in the browser hits your API directly, how are you planning to track them? IP Address?

Comment: It's not decided yet, I need to research that part more but the idea is to use ip, user agent, js execution and so on to try to limit others from downloading all our data through the API. A simple ip+captcha might be enough actually. In the end, we need to get the API calls directly. At least as far as I can tell.

Comment: I still think my answer is sufficient, but you would know better than I. Just be sure to use OAuth 2 to secure your API, and if you do send the token to the browser, then keep it's lifespan short.